# AFNetworking + AFJSONRequestOperation + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, afnetworking

I'm using NSMutableURLRequest before using AFJSONOperationRequest and I have a problems getting the data in my Rails app.

If I use :

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[HTTPClient sharedClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:dict constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) 
  {
  }];
```

Then :

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) 
  { 
    else {
    }
  }
```

I get my data correctly formatted in the Rails logs:

```
Parameters: {"contact"=>{"country_id"=>"45", "lastname"=>"Tutu"}}
```

But I don't need AFMultipartFormData to send a file... (no file to send)

So, instead, I use:

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[HTTPClient sharedClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:dict];
```

with my AFJSONRequestOperation too. But, my parameters are now not set correctly in my rails app:

```
Parameters: {contact[country_id] => "45", contact[lastname] => "Tutu"}
```

instead of

```
Parameters: {"contact"=>{"country_id"=>"45", "lastname"=>"Tutu"}}
```

I don't understand why. It looks like the body of the request is not set correctly when I don't use the block: "constructingBodyWithBlock".

Comment: I am running into the same encoding problem here and still couldn't find a solution. Could you already figure out what the problem was? Oh... and for me it doesn't work WITH the constructingBodyWithBlock part...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use multipartFormRequestWithMethod.

Just use the postPath method like this

```
[[YourHTTPClient sharedClient] postPath:path
   parameters:dict
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSString* path){
      }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      }];
```

**Edit:**

If you need an operation use AFJSONRequestOperation directly

```
+ (AFJSONRequestOperation *)JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
                                                success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON))success 
                                                failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON))failure;


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yoursite.com/path"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation * operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                                }
                                                failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                                }];
```

Comment: Yes, but I build a request in my model... So how to do that with a request and an AFJSONRequestOperation ?